# Return Hibernate entity on UPDATE query

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm trying to use hibernate to make a simple SQL UPDATE query and map the result row into Hibernate entity (Using the `createSQLQuery`).

```
String updateQuery = 
        String.format("UPDATE \"user\" "
                + "SET chips_balance=chips_balance + %d, diamonds_balance=diamonds_balance + %d "
                + "WHERE id=%d", chips_delta, diamonds_delta, userId); 

        User user = (User)session.createSQLQuery(updateQuery).uniqueResult();
```

This throws an Exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Cause:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No results were returned by the query.
```

How can I make this work? (Using the `RETURNING` keyword)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how to achieve it:

```
String updateQuery = 
        String.format(  "UPDATE \"user\" "
            +       "SET chips_balance=chips_balance + %d, diamonds_balance=diamonds_balance + %d "
            +       "WHERE id=%d "
            +       "RETURNING *", 100, 5, 64); 
            
User user = (User) session.createSQLQuery(updateQuery)
        .addEntity(User.class)
        .uniqueResult();
```

The key point here is to use "RETURNING *" and map it to the entity using .addEntity(User.class)